# list will not go under d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

i literally have no idea what is going on, i just followed this repo's tutorial with my own spin.  https://github.com/EpiphanyMachine/d3AngularIntegration

[image]

code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
   <title>heirarchical graph</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"> 
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-custom" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">My <br>Mood</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Their <br>Mood</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our <br>Moods</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Weekly <br>Breakdown</a></li>
      </ul>
      <d3-Circle></d3-Circle> 
    </div>   
   </div>

 <div class="top3">
  <ul id="navlist">
   <li><img class="img-responsive project-image" src="./images/happywink.png" alt="project name" /></li>
   <li><img class="img-responsive project-image" src="./images/laughhard.png" alt="project name" /></li>
   <li><img class="img-responsive project-image" src="./images/smirk.png" alt="project name" /></li>
  </ul>
  </div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
<script src="./js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="./js/d3circle.js"></script>
<script src="./js/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

as you can see, the d3 element is within the angular controller, and the list is outside. for some reason its rendering like this, i have no idea whats going on.

javascript incase someone wanted to see

```
  (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp.directives')
.directive('d3Circle', ['d3', function(d3) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

     d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.texts = +d.texts;
    });  

    var width = (window.innerWidth < 1280) ? 400 : 600,
    height = (window.innerWidth < 1280) ? 400 : 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;


    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);




    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(radius - 70);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .startAngle(1.1*Math.PI)
        .endAngle(3.1*Math.PI)
        .value(function(d) { return d.texts; });

     var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", '50%')
        .attr("height", '50%')
        .attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height)+' '+Math.min(width,height))
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");



      var text1;
      var text2;
      var g = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("d", "arc")
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
          return color(d.data.mood); 
        });

      g.append("path")
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.mood); })
          .transition().delay(function(d, i) { return i * 500; }).duration(500)
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
              var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.1, d.endAngle);
                return function(t) {
                d.endAngle = i(t);
                return arc(d);
            }
          });


      g.on("mouseover", function(d) {
          var total = d3.sum(data.map(function(d) {                // NEW
          return d.texts;                                           // NEW
        })); 

          var percent = Math.round(1000 * d.data.texts / total) / 10;
          text1 = g.append("text")
              .attr("translate", arc.centroid(d))
              .attr("dy", ".5em")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style("fill", "black")
              .attr("class", "on")
              .text(d.data.mood);

           text2 = g.append("text")
              .attr("translate", arc.centroid(d))
              .attr("dy", "25")
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style("fill", "black")
              .attr("class", "on")
              .text(percent + '%');   


      })

        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            text1.remove();
            text2.remove();
        });    

      /*g.append("text")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.data.mood; });*/

    });

    }
  };
}]);

 }());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you append the svg to the body, it will go under the list:

http://api.jquery.com/append/

**Solution #1:**

You can use a div instead of body to avoid that.

**html:**

```
<div id="svgPie"></div>
//svgPie above img list
<div class="top3">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li><img class="img-responsive project-image" src="./images/happywink.png" alt="project name" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-responsive project-image" src="./images/laughhard.png" alt="project name" /></li>
    <li><img class="img-responsive project-image" src="./images/smirk.png" alt=
```

**JS:**

```
var svg = d3.select("#svgPie")
      .append("svg")
```

**Solution #2:**

Just replace:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
```

with:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").insert('svg', ':first-child')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: so do i wrap a div around the surrounding d3 element to fix this?

Comment: first one with modifcation since im using angular directive

           <div id="svgPie>
           <d3-Circle></d3-Circle>
           </div>